# Parse data frame producing CSV with lapply

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to take a data frame and send it to .csv file(s). Here is my sample data using `dput(df)`:

```
df <- structure(list(ident = 1:35, code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Desc = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("lax", "mia", "nyc"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ident", 
"code", "Desc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L
))
```

I'm trying to loop through my data and select only A and output to file.

```
filename <- levels(df$code)

filename2 <- paste0(filename, "_file.csv")
```

Would I use `lapply` to write a file for each code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Map(write.csv,split(df,df$code),filename2)`.

Comment: Wow - Map is just what I needed. Thanks!

So Googling for the term `Map` is quite difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/) solution:

Since you simply want to use a function for its side effects (writing to a file), and don't need to return any values, the walk function from the [purrr](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/) package is appropriate here:

```
library(tidyverse)

walk(unique(df$code), function(x) {write_csv(df %>% filter(code == x), paste0(x, "_file.csv"))})
```

Comment: How would I use the `row.names = FALSE` within this example?

Comment: The `write_csv` function (not to be confused with `write.csv`) never writes row names. Note: `write_csv` is a tidyverse function from the `readr` package, and is about 2x as fast as `write.csv`. If you want to use `write.csv`, you can simply pass `row.names = FALSE` as an argument, like so `...paste0(x, "_file.csv"), row.names = FALSE)})`

Comment: You're right I had them mixed up. I also wanted column names to be False. Your solution was perfect!